# Spring Cloud Dataflow Kafka Topic creation/configuration

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I created a Processor here I will call it my-transform.

And a Stream:

:my-topic > my-transform | log

And I configured the Processor not to auto create Topic with this config
and wrote the Code as a Function Bean.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9093
          auto-create-topics: false
      function:
        bindings:
          transform-in-0: input
          transform-out-0: output
```

The Problem is that the Topic (my-topic) is still created.
But it should not be created.
Instead, I want to create with another application.
So it can be configured with the right retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

In my Kafka installation, `autoCreateTopicsEnable` was still enabled.